# Kernel panic using logelevel or quiet

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I am using an embedded device with onboard storage (mmcblk0).

The system is using UEFI (and GRUB), on mmcblk0 I have a GPT partition with 3 partition: root, configurations, swap.

My command to boot is:

`linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 net.ifnames=0 splash`

Now my problem is that when I set the quiet or loglevel param, it fails to boot and hangs up in a kernel panic. When I don't set one of those it boots perfectly. Root param is always the same.

Full kernel panic log:

[image: kernel panic log]

Comment: How do you set quiet? Like this `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 net.ifnames=0 quiet splash`?

Comment: @mmmint correct. Either before or after splash, Loglevel can be 0-7, no matter which level i set, all end in a kernel crash.

Answer (score 0):

It seems root FS is not ready when you kernel tries to load it. Use rootwait or rootdelay in your kernel command line should solve the issue.

Comment: Why do you suppose this would be correlated with the `quiet`/ `loglevel` setting?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.